# Displaying external SVG image from URL in react native

Tags: react-native, svg

Is there any package that would allow me to display SVG image loaded from external URL?

I've tried to use react-native-svg-image / react-native-svg-uri and their forks but none of those are working correctly - is there any non dead package for react-native that would do the job?

This is the sample error being thrown by svg-img-uri

```
<SvgUri width="24" height="24" source={{ uri: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.3.0/flags/1x1/ad.svg' }} />
```

```
Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component.

This error is located at:
    in RNSVGDefs (at Defs.js:8)
```

Answer (score 25):

react-native-svg now supports display svg from online uri

```
import { SvgUri } from 'react-native-svg';

export default () => (
  <SvgUri
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    uri="http://demo.com/assets/your/image.svg"
  />
);
```

Reference https://github.com/react-native-svg/react-native-svg#use-with-content-loaded-from-uri

Answer (score 2):

The url doesnt' have any quotes around it. That might be the problem

```
<SvgUri 
 width="24" 
 height="24" 
 source={{ uri: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.3.0/flags/1x1/ad.svg'}} />
```

Comment: I was asking about React-Native

Comment: There seem to be no quotes around the url

Comment: Could forgot about them but nope - that's not a problem. Can't find any working component for that - like whole react native SVG is dead everywhere.

Comment: What's it say now?

Comment: Same error  - I just forgot to add brackets in my comment. They cannot solve it on bitbucket there and looks like other forked projects are failing too.

Answer (score -1):

This [Github issue](https://github.com/vault-development/react-native-svg-uri/issues/150) might help you.

If you still do not succeed, you can still convert your SVG file to a React Native Component using https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/svgr/playground/ (don't forget to toggle React-native in the left panel)

Comment: I cannot - I fetch images from external API. Nothing is working from what they are trying to github, have no idea whether React Native is dead or something.